# How to have Register-ObjectEvent run in background?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that's using PowerShell's `Register-ObjectEvent` to watch a folder for changes. Since the Register-ObjectEvent only works while the PowerShell session is active, I need to keep a PowerShell window open - which I'd rather not do.

I'd like to know if there is there a way to run `Register-ObjectEvent` in the background somehow?

Comment: If you have powershell 3 or higher, you can run a powershell session in the background. (Finally got right link) http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847783.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register-ObjectEvent will only run during the PowerShell session.  WMI offers the ability to subscribe to WMI events (like new files or changes to files) and to run commands based on that, so you might want to investigate [permanent WMI event registrations](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/20/use-powershell-to-create-a-permanent-wmi-event-to-launch-a-vbscript.aspx)