# Keep Register-ObjectEvent when logged off

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which uses Register-ObjectEvent along with IO.FileSystemWatcher to monitor a folder for new files being dropped in.

Once I log off the folder is no longer monitored and when I login again I cannot see anything when I run Get-EventSubscriber.

Is there a way to keep Events Subscribed after I log off so they keep on running when no user is logged on?

Thanks for the answers. For anyone finding this in the future I've gone down the WmiEvent route which should survive logoff/reboot.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362825/how-to-have-register-objectevent-run-in-background/27363074#27363074 ?

Comment: Can you point us to a Stackoverflow post that describes the WmiEvent route? #needAlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriptions with Register-ObjectEvents are limited to the current PowerShell session. If you log out, your session is gone. You could run your PowerShell Script as a scheduled task using the Windows Task scheduler. That way it would be independent of your current login session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've went for the WMI approach instead.